# R glm anova. Putting in each individual term as first sequentially, or using chi squared to see the effect of each individual term

Tags: r, glm, anova

Need a hand analysing a model which I've built. I've built a model which analyses the effects of a number of variables on the chances that someone quits smoking. The output of the model is as follows:

[image]

I want to run anova on the model using Chi squared. The current way I am doing this is as follows, where each term is added sequentially:

[image]

As well as the effect of dependance, I also want to see the effect of each other variables in the same way so that they're able to be compared. At the moment, if I am to This means that I need to do one of the following:

> 1. Do anova, adding each term first sequentially. At the moment, the only way I can think to do this is to write a new model for each variable, adding this variable in first e.g. [image]

> 2. Run anova, but add each term comparing the model with it to the model without it. How I do this I'm not sure though...

Any help or advice on how to achieve any of these would be great! Please ask for any more details!

Comment: Really the wrong place for this question. There is a statistics-focussed forum where this would be on topic. Voting to migrate there.

Comment: Try `car::Anova()`.